# Is this series convergent or divergent $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\dfrac{\arctan{n}}{n^{2}+1}} $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have problem with convergence $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\dfrac{\arctan{n}}{n^{2}+1}} $$

I should use integral test for convergence.

Thanks for help.

Comment: ...$arctan(n)<2$

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that limit comparison test can't be used. It's too easy...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In integral test for convergence $\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty f(n)$ is convergent or divergent if the improper integral $\int_{1}^\infty f(x)\,dx$ is convergent or divergent.  But, You have to check three conditions:

1) functon $f(x)=\dfrac{arctan{x}}{x^{2}+1}$
 is positive for $ x \ge 1$

2) continuous  for $ x \ge 1$

3) and $f'(x)=\dfrac{1-2x\arctan{x}}{(x^2+1)^2}$ so $f(x)$ is monotone decreasing  for $ x \ge 1$ .

Now, we may use this test.

$$\int_{1}^\infty {\dfrac{arctan{x}}{x^{2}+1}}\,dx$$

$$lim_{\epsilon\to\infty}\int_{1}^\epsilon{\dfrac{arctan{x}}{x^{2}+1}\,dx}$$

$\arctan{x}=t$

$\dfrac1{x^2+1}\,dx=\,dt$

$$lim_{\epsilon\to\infty}\int_{1}^\epsilon{t\,dt}= lim_{\epsilon\to\infty}[\dfrac1{2}t^2+C]_1^\epsilon=lim_{\epsilon\to\infty}\dfrac1{2}[(\arctan{\epsilon})^2+C -\arctan{1} -C]= \dfrac1{2}(\dfrac{\pi}{2})^2-\dfrac{\pi}{4}$$

This integral is convergent, so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\dfrac{\arctan{n}}{n^{2}+1}} $ is convergent too.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\dfrac{\arctan{n}}{n^{2}+1}}<\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\dfrac{\frac12\pi}{n^{2}+1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Use limit comparison test with $1/n^2$.

Answer (score 0):

You sum is smaller than
$$
\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{2}{n^2+1}<2\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n^2}\le \frac{\pi^2}{3}.
$$